# How can I enter the value of a cell within another but want some part of string around it? For eg: I need "marks(/<value in cell M3>)" in cell C3

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have already tried putting the formula but can't get through as I have **some parts to be manually entered** and **then the value to be taken from another cell**.

Comment: Do you mean: `="marks(/"&M3&")"`

Comment: or maybe you want to use `=CONCATENATE` an example would help!

Comment: I want the result on a table header field. So when I apply `="marks(/"&M3&")"`, it returns value zero and the formula disappears. @Rory
.The same goes for the `=CONCATENATE()`. @Kevin

Comment: include a data table here and explain further to understand your exact needs instead of making us guessing.

Comment: You cannot have a formula in the header cell for a table column.